# How PyQt understand that our class is inheriting from something?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I was recently digging a lot in PyQt and doing some staff with it, but suddenly realized , I don't understand some basic staff which I was doing. How class which inherits let's say from QGraphicsView becomes QGraphicsView itself or how it becomes QWidget ? Also as far as I understand when you inherit from something , class just getting all the methods from class you inherit. Here is some code below :

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as QtWidgets
import PyQt5.QtCore as QtCore


class First(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(First, self).__init__(parent)
        print('hello')

class Window(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.window = 'test'
        self.title = 'test'
        self.size = (1000, 650)
        self.create()

    def create(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.resize(QtCore.QSize(*self.size))
        self.graphicsWidget = First(self)

        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout( )
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window( )
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show( )
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))
```

For example in this code , I made class called 'First' and it's inheriting from `QtWidgets.QGraphicsView` and then I am adding it as a widget to *mainLayout* inside my Window class. Until now, I was taking it as a granted and didn't think about it much, but can somebody explain to me how my `mainLayout.addWidget()` which accepting only QWidgets , understands that in front of him is QWidget ? Because if you do `print(type(First))` it will give `<class 'sip.wrappertype'>` not a widget. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inheritance is aimed at the specialization of a class, that is, the inherited class must have specific characteristics that the class from which it inherits.

---

QGraphicsView is a QWidget, because if you do the QGraphicsView inherence diagram:

```
┌--------------┐   ┌--------------┐ 
|   QObject    |   | QPaintDevice |
└------┬-------┘   └-------┬------┘ 
       |                   |
       └---------┬---------┘
                 |
          ┌------┴------┐
          |   QWidget   |
          └------┬------┘
                 |
          ┌------┴------┐
          |   QFrame    |
          └------┬------┘
                 |
       ┌---------┴---------┐
       |QAbstractScrollArea|
       └---------┬---------┘
                 |
       ┌---------┴---------┐
       |   QGraphicsView   |
       └-------------------┘
```

From it it follows that:

- QGraphicsView is a QAbstractScrollArea.
- QGraphicsView is a QFrame.
- QGraphicsView is a QWidget.
- QGraphicsView is a QObject.
- QGraphicsView is a QPaintDevice.

---

**Why `print(type(First))` returns `<class 'sip.wrappertype'>`?**

If the [docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/sip/using.html#types-and-meta-types) are reviewed:

> [...]
>  SIP implements two super-types, sip.simplewrapper and
>   sip.wrapper, and a meta-type, sip.wrappertype.
>
> sip.simplewrapper is the super-type of sip.wrapper. The super-type of
>   sip.simplewrapper is object.
>
> sip.wrappertype is the meta-type of both sip.simplewrapper and
>   sip.wrapper. The super-type of sip.wrappertype is type.
>
> sip.wrapper supports the concept of object ownership described in
>   Ownership of Objects and, by default, is the super-type of all the
>   types that SIP generates.
>   [...]

From it it follows that sip.wrappertype is the metaclass of QObject. And that's what you're doing since `type(FooClass)` returns the metaclass of FooClass.

If you want to print the class you must use the object:

```py
print(type(self.graphicsWidget))
```

Output:

```py
<class '__main__.First'>
```

To identify that an object is of a class (or its parent classes) you can use the following methods, for example if it is a QWidget:

**1.**

```py
if isinstance(obj, QtWidgets.QWidget):
    print("is QWidget")
```

**2.** If it's a QObject

**2.1**

```py
if qobject.inherits("QWidget"):
    print("is QWidget")
```

**2.2**

```py
if qobject.isWidgetType():
    print("is QWidget")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `First()` instance is also an instance of `QtWidgets.QGraphicsView` precisely because you said so, i.e. you made the class inherit from `QtWidgets.QGraphicsView`. You can check this:

```
f = First()
isinstance(f, QtWidgets.QGraphicsView)  # True
```

Since `QtWidgets.QGraphicsView`in turn inherits from `QtWidgets.QWidget`, the following is also True:

```
isinstance(f, PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget)
```

Thus, `addWidget` happily accepts the instance as a `QWidget`. (Note that `addWidget` does not have to do explicit type checking on the instance it receives. The code could work solely due to the fact that the instance "quacks like a duck", i.e. it has the appropriate QWidget methods).